# C# Detect windows restart and stop

Tags: c#, windows

I was wondering if there is a way to intercept a restart which has been executed by and external application, so i can post a command to an API to say the machine is restarting and then restart the machine myself?

Regards

B

Comment: A shutdown or restart should be _detectable_ but I doubt it is possible to cancel it from "user space" or even be granted enough time to make an API call _reliably_.

Comment: You can use `WM_ENDSESSION` event to detect shutdown. Then, you can use ShutdownBlockReasonCreate to block the shutdown until your call is done. Here's a blog post with more details https://www.meziantou.net/prevent-windows-shutdown-or-session-ending-in-dotnet.htm